# How to split directory names in bash to make recursive call in all directories in a path

Tags: shell, makefile

Sorry about the confusing title, I had a hard time describing the problem.

I have two values available to me, the first one is a constant and the second one could be any number of folder levels

```
BASE = application/classes
FOLDERS = types/ads
```

Based on those, I need to run commands like the following (in that order):

```
verifyDir application/classes
verifyDir application/classes/types
verifyDir application/classes/types/ads
```

I could also just pass all the directories to `verifyDir` if that's easier

```
verifyDir application/classes application/classes/types application/classes/types/ads
```

This is within a makefile, so using gmake's functions is acceptable.

Please don't answer with a suggestion to restructure what I am doing. It would take way too long to explain why I need this.

Comment: @downvoter: What is wrong with the question? Help me improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a gmake master, so I can just propose a way how to achieve that using shell, may be it helps you to achieve that in gnu make...

```
BASE=application/classes
FOLDERS=types/ads

verifyDir $BASE
NEWBASE=$BASE
for c in `echo $FOLDERS | tr "/" " "`; do
    NEWBASE="$NEWBASE/$c"
    verifyDir $NEWBASE
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Andrew's suggestion is great. Somebody at work came up up with another solution so I'll put it here for reference since it uses a different technique (IFS, which changes the default word separator)

```
BASE="some/base/dir" 
TAIL="fold1/fold2/fold3" 
ALLPATHS="$BASE"
IFS=/
for X in $TAIL; do
    ALLPATHS="$ALLPATHS $ALLPATHS/$X";
done; 
unset IFS; 
verifyDir $ALLPATHS;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using GNU make functions

```
BASE = application/classes
FOLDERS = types/ads/more/hierarchy/here

FOLDERS_SPLIT := $(subst /, ,$(FOLDERS))
FOLDERS_ITER :=

FOLDERS_TREE := $(foreach FOLDER, $(FOLDERS_SPLIT), $(eval FOLDERS_ITER := $(FOLDERS_ITER)/$(FOLDER)) $(BASE)$(FOLDERS_ITER))

all:
    @echo FOLDERS_TREE $(FOLDERS_TREE)
```